# iPhone screen recording is losing sound when exporting on iOS11

Tags: iphone, video, screen-capture

I have a well functioning screen recording with sound on my iPhone. When I try to share it via WhatsApp, save it in Dropbox or upload it to YouTube, it loses the audio. The picture is still there, but no sound is present. When played on the iPhone the audio works as expected.

This problem has occurred many times and the video is not broken. What is causing the issue and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of iOS running on your iPhone. If it is iOS 11, you may want to take a look at question and accepted answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304421/missing-sound-in-videos-recorded-with-ios-11?rq=1) that may be germane to your problem.

Comment: It is ideed iOS 11. Was searching for the question but did not found it. Is it fixed in iOS12?

Comment: @Predicate It wasn't fixed in iOS 12 and is not fixed in iOS 12.1 still.